# replace a substring in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a test file like:

```
rd20140921
rd20131122 rd20131122
hello?rd20131122
rd20140921
rd20140921
```

---

and my python code to replace any string which is 10 characters long and starts with rd201 with current date is

```
filesToSearch=["test.txt"];
textToReplace = "rd"+today.isoformat().replace("-","");
print ("Text to replace: %s" % textToReplace);

for file in filesToSearch:
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(file,inplace=1):
        line = re.sub(r"^rd201[0-9]{5}$", textToReplace, line)
        print(line, end='');
```

this code replace only line 1 4 and 5 not 2 and 3.

Comment: That is not what your regular expression says... The `$` at the end of the expression indicates the end of a string.

Comment: And `^` indicates the beginning. Line 3 doesn't begin with this. Get rid of those two tokens and it should replace everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is not matching exactly what you think it is. The `$` character matches the end of a string so lines 1,4,5 are the only lines that match the expression.

For the string: `rd20131122 rd20131122`, you match the first `rd20131122` but that is not the end of the string, so the match fails.

For the string: `hello?rd20131122`, it doesn't match your expression that states the string should *start* with `rd201`. It starts with `hello` and so the expression doesn't match it.

If you would like to replace **all occurrences** of strings that contain the expression `rd201[0-9]{5}` then all you have to do is remove the string start (`^`) and string end (`$`) parts of your regular expression.